# Set dataSource of ListView programmatically

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to update a windows 8 application from the Developer Preview to the Consumer Preview. It seems there's been a few changes. This code used to work:

```
var myDataSource = new WinJS.UI.ArrayDataSource(array)
var basicListView = WinJS.UI.getControl(document.getElementById("basicListView"));
basicListView.dataSource = myDataSource;
```

Now, there is no WinJS.UI.getControl method and no ArrayDataSource. This is my code:

```
var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(array);
var list = document.getElementById("basicListView");
list.itemDataSource = dataList.dataSource;
```

but it does nothing (except add a property to a DOM element that is ignored). Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Got it. To get the control you now use the winControl property of the element:

```
var list = document.getElementById("basicListView").winControl;
```

Setting the itemDataSource works a treat.